# Character encoding in filters of datatable

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, datatable

I'm using DataTables to work with data but there is a problem with language specific characters like Ě, Š, Č, ... I have city "Třebíč" but if I enter "Třebíč" into searchbox, the data that come to server are "tÅebÃ­Ä". The charset is UTF-8 in every page.

Is it possible to work with these characters in JavaScript and DataTables?

Adding to this, am using datatable server side processing. My Spring MVC controller sends the response data.

This is working on my local tomcat which is liferay tomcat on windows. But not when same is hosted on a linux machine.